# What is the correct linking order of SFML external libs in static mode?

Tags: static, linker, sfml

I'm trying to compile a simple SFML program test in static mode, i defined SFML_STATIC before any sfml  header inclusion, i use "-s-d" prefixed libs for it.

I added the extlibs using this order:
    mingw32
    user32
    gdi32
    winmm
    dxguid
    libfreetype.a
    libglew.a
    libjpeg.a
    libopenal.a
    libsndfile.a

I finally got a lot of undefined reference to glfunctions and GLEW_ARB_texture... to FT_Fond_Face, etc.

(Note: When i use dynamic linking which needs Dll files, no reference problem occurs, i use Windows 7, sfml-gcc-4.7.1-tdm-32bit, and codeBlocks 13.12)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correct linking order of sfml extlibs are given here for each of sfml module http://www.sfml-dev.org/faq.php#tr-cb-linker :)